# XmlSerializer crashing on Xml document

Tags: xml, string, serialization

I extracted the following node from XmlReader:

```
string xml = "<FeatureType xmlns=\"http://www.opengis.net/wfs\" > </FeatureType>"
```

In order to deserialize to a predefined class, I attempted:

```
using (StringReader elementReader = new StringReader("<?xml version='1.0'?>" + xml ))
{
    // TODO: Can data contract serializer be used?
    XmlSerializer deserializer = serializers[typeof(FeatureType)];
    featureTypes.Add((FeatureType)deserializer.Deserialize(elementReader));
}
```

Upon deserialization, XmlSerializer throws an exception with the following message:

```
"<FeatureType xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/wfs'> was not expected."
```

If I remove the namespace declaration, I can deserialize.  Without having to further manipulate with the output of the reader, how do I fix this?  Also, why is the reader injecting the namespace declaration, when it extracts each node?

TIA.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the xml variable in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure you use the default XML namespace when you construct your `XmlSerializer` for this class:

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FeatureType), 
                                               "http://www.opengis.net/wfs");
```

This is the constructor for `XmlSerializer` which takes an optional second parameter, `defaultNamespace`.

Using this approach, you can easily deserialize your XML string without any problem whatsoever.